# PHP Contact Form Not Working on Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, email

I built a simple php contact form using mail(). This form has worked on my website for years.

However, I recently built a new website on wordpress. I pretty much copied and pasted the same form, however, I do not receive any email. When I hit submit, the form simply redirects to the homepage/index layout, but has the contact form url.

On the original site, however, a message is printed on a blank screen confirming the email was sent. I also tested the original code on the original site and it works.

contact_form.php:

```
 <?php
    /*
        Template Name: Contact Form
   `*/

    include( 'header.php');
?>

<?php

    if(have_posts()): while (have_posts()): the_post();
?>


<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="message">

      <div class="text">
        <?php the_content(); ?>
        <form action="contact_form_script.php" method="post">
            <p>Your email address:</p> <input type="text" name="emailAddress">
            <p>Subject:</p> <input type="text" name="subject"> 
            <p>Message:</p> <textarea name="message"></textarea>

            <input type="text" name="honeyPot" style="display: none;">

            <br />
            <input type="submit" name="email_form" value="SUBMIT"/>
        </form>

        <br />
        <br />


      </div>
    </div>
</div>

<?php
    endwhile;
    endif;
?>

<?php
    include('footer.php');
?>
```

contact_form_script.php

```
<?php

    $to= 'myEmailAddress@email.com';

    $from = "FROM: Email@myDomain.com"; 

    $replyTo=$_POST['emailAddress']; /*whatever the user input*/

    $headers= $from ."\r\n" .'Reply-To: '. $replyTo; 

    //Have also tried just $_POST['subject']; Still doesn't work
    $subj="Subject: "+$_POST['subject'];

    $msg=$_POST['message'];

    $spam=$_POST['honeyPot'];

    if (empty($spam)){
        mail($to, $subj, $msg, $headers);
    };

    Print "Thank you for email! <br /> <br /> <a href='/'><--BACK</a>"


?>
```

Also, is there a better way to test a form like this to see errors or troubleshoot in some way other than just checking to see if I got the email?

Comment: you're missing an ending quote here: `$to= 'myEmailAddress@email.com;`

Comment: Thank you. That was a typo. Fixed in the question. Still does not send with quotes

Comment: have you var_dumped $spam to make sure there's a value assigned?

Comment: Where abouts on the server are your scripts stored? Looking at contact_form.php this looks like it is a part of a theme/template.
Where is 'contact_from_script.php'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways in WordPress to accomplish what you are trying to do.

Currently your form action is pointing at `contact_form_script.php` which assumes that this script is in the current directory. But that current directory is not relative to your `contact_form.php`. It is relative to the users current path. eg www.mysite.com/contact/.

One quick (but lazy) way of solving your problem would be to move `contact_form_script.php` into the root WordPress directory of your site. Then change the `form action="/contact_form_script.php"` (Note the `/`) causing it to post to a file called `contact_form_script.php` in the root site dir.

A better method would be to keep `contact_form_script.php` in your template directory and include it in your functions.php.

If we use the `email_form` submit input to let WordPress know the `contact_form_script.php` script needs to be loaded, this should allow you to load the whole of wordpress core and still have your custom form handling script deal with the data:

functions.php:

```
if (!empty($_POST['email_form'])) {
    require_once(__DIR__.'/contact_form_script.php');
    // You could put a die() here if you wanted the script to stop executing.
}
```

contact_form.php:

```
include( 'header.php');

if(have_posts()): while (have_posts()): the_post();


<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="message">

      <div class="text">
        <?php the_content(); ?>
        <form action="" method="post"> <!-- Notice we are now submitting our data to wordpress and not directly to our form script -->
            <p>Your email address:</p> <input type="text" name="emailAddress">
            <p>Subject:</p> <input type="text" name="subject"> 
            <p>Message:</p> <textarea name="message"></textarea>

            <input type="text" name="honeyPot" style="display: none;">

            <br />
            <input type="submit" name="email_form" value="SUBMIT"/>
        </form>

        <br />
        <br />


      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Again this isn't ideal, but I suspect is what you are looking for at this point in time, and it is a step in the right direction. Keeping your code within your template.

Comment: Thank you, this helped! I didn't follow it completely, but as I'm new to WP I forgot about the pathing issue. I changed ` <form action="contact_form_script.php" method="post">` to '<form action=<?php echo get_template_directory_uri().'/contact_form_script.php' ?> method="post">' and it works. That's still acceptable?

Comment: Of course... whatever works for you is acceptable. :)

Answer (score 1):

Change the following

```
 mail($to, $subj, $msg, $headers);
```

Into

```
wp_mail($to, $subj, $msg, $headers);
```

This will let WordPress properly route your mail.

Also as a whole... you should use wp_ajax to do this you can use it without writing any javascript... create a file that you include in functions with the following.

```
function process_contact_form() {

$to= 'myEmailAddress@email.com';

$from = "FROM: Email@myDomain.com"; 

$replyTo=$_POST['emailAddress']; /*whatever the user input*/

$headers= $from ."\r\n" .'Reply-To: '. $replyTo; 

//Have also tried just $_POST['subject']; Still doesn't work
$subj="Subject: "+$_POST['subject'];

$msg=$_POST['message'];

$spam=$_POST['honeyPot'];

if (empty($spam)){
    wp_mail($to, $subj, $msg, $headers);
};

header('Location:'.$_REQUEST['_wp_http_referer']);
wp_die();

}
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_process_contact_form', 'process_contact_form' );
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_process_contact_form', 'process_contact_form' );
```

Change your template file to

```
 <?php
    /*
        Template Name: Contact Form
   `*/

    include( 'header.php');
?>

<?php

    if(have_posts()): while (have_posts()): the_post();
?>


<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="message">

      <div class="text">
        <?php the_content(); ?>
        <form action="<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>" method="post">
            <p>Your email address:</p> <input type="text" name="emailAddress">
            <p>Subject:</p> <input type="text" name="subject"> 
            <p>Message:</p> <textarea name="message"></textarea>
            <?php wp_referer_field(true); ?>
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="process_contact_form">

            <input type="text" name="honeyPot" style="display: none;">

            <br />
            <input type="submit" name="email_form" value="SUBMIT"/>
        </form>

        <br />
        <br />


      </div>
    </div>
</div>

<?php
    endwhile;
    endif;
?>

<?php
    include('footer.php');
?>
```

Comment: Thank you. What is the difference between using mail() and wp_mail()? What do you mean by "properly route you mail." ? And why use wp_ajax over the original method? Is this just a preference or a requirement? Just trying to better understand, as thanks to first answer it is working, but not sure if this is the more appropriate solution, or just an alternative?

Comment: Ah sorry for the lack of context, let me clarify.

Comment: mail() is the default PHP function for mailing things.
wp_mail() is a wrapper for the same that can be extended using plugins and more. It has logging and a few other features to it that make it useful. It's also considered better practice when trying to do things The WordPress Way
Using wp_ajax is just a preference. It allows you to keep your app code which processes the contact form separate from the template. Using wp_referrer_fields allows you to increase the reusability of your contact form by not having to duplicate your template each time you want to send them somewhere else.

Comment: And when I say properly route your mail, I mean allowing plugins or anything else you have on the system to do things with your email before it goes out. (Logging, Modification, Duplication etc) or even so far as to modify using your machines default mailserver to using something like a gmail account to send email when working on a test machine.

Comment: Thanks this was helpful. The other answer directly fixed it though. This was helpful because I now see firsthand why it's useful because I can't use WP code on the contact_form_script.php script. So I couldn't get_theme_mod() for the email address, or include the header/footer to style the page.

Comment: I completely forgot to mention that WP related functions and anything else that you've put into your separated logic will be available as well for the exact reasons you've just described!

Answer (score 0):

We recently faced a similar problem with our contact form. Apparently, the problem was not a result of a problem with our PHP, but rather a change in shared-hosting policies. Naturally, if you are using a VPS this would not be a problem.

However, if you have any form of shared hosting using cPanel and any form of script based email (including Contact Form 7) this can be a potential solution.

Using the "paper lantern" theme, chose the option "Registered Mail IDs" as below:
[image: link to choose]

Then you should get an option to add additional email IDs. Just enter your email ID that you use in the script. In roughly around 8 hours the ID should have been propagated and you will be able to use your script.

Hope this helps! Took us a really long time to figure out.